# Boot loop with certain Sata to USB adaptors

Tags: linux, boot, usb-3, kernel-module

So in my persuite to try and get some servers running on two Raspberry Pi 4, I ran into some boot problems. This is the setup.

2 x Pi 4 that is booting from an SDCard with UEFI. They then boot up from two 2.5 inch SSD's connected to one of the USB3 ports on each Pi. One of the Pi's is supposed to run 2 3.5 inch HDD's with ZFS at some point, so I have bought two Sata/USB convertes from delock that only supplies 5V for the two SSD's and two other Sata/USB convertes from Hama, that also supplies 12V for the 3.5 inch mechanical disks. Because the two Hama converters arrived first, I used those to setup Ubuntu 20.04 on the Pi's, which was working fine. The problem came when I replaced the Hama converters with the delock ones.

Now I could no longer boot Ubuntu on either of the Pi's, not until I tried switching back to the Hama converters. The problem I got, was a boot loop of USB resets on the SSD's.

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#14 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CWD IN 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 08 00 
scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start 
usb 3-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd 
scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

This is what just continues again and again. I traced this to UAS, which the Hama converter does not use. So I tried blacklisting 'uas', forcing it to use 'usb_storage' directly, but this just ends up in a kernel panic, because it cannot locate the root partition. It did however work on a live install image of Ubuntu, which also did not boot for the same reason. From here I could read the disk and it's partitions fine. Blacklisting UAS just does not work on the actual installed system.

I remember that I had a similar issue a while back on a USB Disk with a live installer of Solus, where it did not boot, because it reset the disk on boot. I did not do much bug tracking then, because a simple USB Disk replacement did the job. But it seams that Linux has a problem with certain usb controllers. Just not sure what and how to fix it.

**B.t.w.**
I did update the kernel, twice. First from 5.8 to 5.11 and then to 5.13. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more testing, I did get this to boot. Seams that simply blacklisting the `uas` module breaks boot. However adding `usb-storage.quirks=<device-id>` to the kernel cmd line, which also forces it to use normal usb storage module, fixes the problem.

At least this way I can use the DeLock controller, but it does not really provide much of an answer to the problems. Why does a `quirks` option on `usb-storage` work rather than blacklisting `uas`? And why does `uas` fail to begin with? Why does the USB-3.1 Hama controller not use `uas` but the USB-3.0 from DeLock do, and how can one make sure what uses what before buying these products?

**EDIT**:
Further testing shows that the Hama product already has a `quirks` match within the `usb-storage` module, which explains why it simply works out-of-box. Not sure what the point is with `uas` then, taken into account that products that are built for it, only works with this feature disabled.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)